# Flow not firing on the 1st of the month?

Tags: apex, workflow, formula, visual-workflow

We are using this quite simple formula to calculate and set the end date where we take the current date then add the number of months the user enters (Terms_Other__c).   However, it's not firing on the first of the month and leave the field blank.   Any ideas how to enhance this formula?  We just need Date today + number of months = end date.

```
DATE(Year({!$Flow.CurrentDate})+floor((MONTH({!$Flow.CurrentDate}) + {!sovOpp.Terms_Other__c}  - 1) / 12) , mod(MONTH({!$Flow.CurrentDate}) + {!sovOpp.Terms_Other__c}  -1, 12) + 1 ,  DAY({!$Flow.CurrentDate}) - 1)
```

Comment: What do you have that triggers the flow to run?

Comment: @JaredT it's autolaunched based on a date field that is coming back from DocuSign - date signed, and the number of months is added by the sales rep

Comment: So the evaluated date coming from this formula will be used to determine when your sequence of automated emails (sent via a time-based workflow) ends?

Comment: The problem is that when the flow is launched (once the date is added), it's using the above formula but not returning a date for it on the first of the month (to populate the end date field).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is with the part that calculates the day of the month.

```
DAY({!$Flow.CurrentDate}) - 1
```

If the current flow day is the 1st then it will try and create a zero date and then things start breaking.

If you aren't too concerned about adjusting the corresponding month you could just wrap it in a `MAX`. E.g.

```
MAX(1,DAY({!$Flow.CurrentDate}) - 1)
```

There are likely other problems with this when the `Terms_Other__c` modifies the month. E.g. When going from a month with 31 days to February.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try to wrap it, otherwise maybe break down the formula to some other actions for the flow.